# Can we use "morning" to describe half a day? How to say half a day using an adjective?

Tags: meaning, adjectives

I don't know how to use an adjective word to describe the same meaning of half a day. E.g. I have done all the work in the morning. In this sentence, "in the morning" means from 08:00 am to 11:59 am or what?

Comment: *I did it all this morning* is a natural thing to say.  It's not clear what you are asking though.  Can you give us a sentence with a blank where you'd like to insert the word you're looking for?

Comment: Why not *forenoon*, which is a bit too formal, of course? " The period of time between sunrise and noon; morning" -- In fact, *morning* is fine, as well.

Comment: There is 'matutinal' which is used very rarely; the attributive noun usage (of 'morning') is common.

Comment: *morning* is **not** an adjective in your example sentence.

Comment: @Kris: these days, I don't think *forenoon* is used anywhere except maybe on boats.

Comment: @Jim Thanks for your help, and I think I just want to ask the question that what's the precise hrs to the word of 'Morning'. Anyway, thank you very much!

Comment: @Kris Hi,Kris! Thanks for your kindly help. The precise hrs of "Morning" is same as "forenoon"?

Comment: I feel a heel saying 'that's _kind_ help', David. But once a teacher, always a teacher, I suppose ;-) Oh, and thank you.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth  really? forget about my wrong using. but sincerely, Thank you. best regards, David

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're looking for a term that describes the hours between midnight and noon, you can  use *"A.M."*

Answer (score 0):

Consider "[matinal](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/matinal)/matin" to refer to the **early** morning, i.e. the small hours before dawn.

> matin/[matinal](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/matinal): of or relating to [matins](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/matins) or the early part of the day.

[The forest, still damp from a matinal rain, was splattered all over with shifting colors of silver and soot.](http://books.google.com.br/books?id=KNeABxGI7vcC&pg=PA64&lpg=PA64&dq=%22matinal+rain%22&source=bl&ots=aHpXUkzZr7&sig=VEVTE1fQSQEXYPwSoVO9AsvxnH8&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ei=s-JYU5jnLIOn0QWOlYD4BA&ved=0CDEQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=%22matinal%20rain%22&f=false)

[Working my way up Washington Street, the only matinal activity I pass is that of the meatpackers.](http://books.google.com.br/books?id=VikLqrttVesC&pg=PT175&lpg=PT175&dq=%22matinal+activity%22&source=bl&ots=ZkhiqojgW6&sig=fvu1BDiYaGEJw_NpkUPVOetMTck&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ei=l-NYU9ieC8TpPLO3gMgO&ved=0CEMQ6AEwBQ#v=onepage&q=%22matinal%20activity%22&f=false)

- "Matin" can also be used as a [noun](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/matin) with a fairly horse-and-buggy flavor to it.

> matin: *obsolete* : (early) morning. E.g. The glow worm shows the matin to be near.

[We discussed that opinion which appeared in the Matin of September 17th.](http://digicoll.library.wisc.edu/cgi-bin/FRUS/FRUS-idx?type=turn&id=FRUS.FRUS1934v05&entity=FRUS.FRUS1934v05.p0436&isize=text)

[In the Matin of Saturday last it was announced for the third times that bombs have been thrown by German aircrafts upon the Swiss territory.](http://www.flightglobal.com/FlightPDFArchive/1915/1915%20-%200290.PDF)

[Dlr., of Georgia, representing the Committee vu in the matin, of this bill, stated that...](http://query.nytimes.com/gst/abstract.html?res=F30C12FF345B127B93C1AB178ED85F428784F9)l

Alternatively, adjectival "[antemeridional](http://penelope.uchicago.edu/~grout/encyclopaedia_romana/romanurbs/horologium.html)" [before noon] could work for "morning," but it has way too little currency in modern day English to be considered a valid option.

Answer (score 0):

morning, pre-noon - afternoon, evening, pre-midnight, post-midnight

Comment: Exactly what I want! Many thanks for your kindly help,DisplayName.

Comment: But could you please tell me the exact time for each item? Thanks! E.g. Morning=5:00-8:00? pre-noon=8:00-11:59? 12:00=noon?

Comment: I don't know anyone who says "pre-noon" or "pre-midnight"

Comment: @Jim actually，me too. I haven't seen this two words using frequently.